# Browser Dependent Image Resizing

Tags: html

So, I have the code below and ideally the goal is to have any images present hit a maximum width of 120px for browsers with viewports of 641px+ and then only a maximum width of 27px. The odd part is that if I remove the resizing coding and put it in a separate code block at the bottom of my site it will resize all images on the page, but not how it's supposed to. When I remove the  portion of coding, the coding seems to try and work a little more, but not exactly. Maybe there's a different way to do the resizing coding?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      @media screen and ( min-width: 641px ){
        img {
          width: 120px;
          height: auto;
        }
      }
      @media screen and ( max-width: 640px ){
        img {
          width: 27px;
          height: auto;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <!--VGC Year-->
      <p style="font-size: 30px">
        <b>
          VGC 2015
        </b>
      </p>

  <!-- Acronym-->
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b style="font-size: 20px">
          CHALK - - - 
        </b>
      </td>

  <!--Arconym Pokemon-->
      <td>
        <img src="https://www.serebii.net/art/th/488.png">
      </td>
      <td>  
        <img src="https://www.serebii.net/art/th/485.png">
      </td>
      <td> 
        <img src="https://www.serebii.net/art/th/591.png">
      </td>
      <td> 
        <img src="https://www.serebii.net/art/th/645-s.png">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="https://www.serebii.net/art/th/115-m.png">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <!--Arconym descption-->
      <p>
        This acronym refers to a five Pokemon core consisting of Cresselia, Heatran, Amoonguss, Landorus-Therian, and Mega Kangaskhan with the sixth and final Pokemon being up to a Trainer's personal preference. This sixth Pokemon was typically added on to the end of the acronym and was considered a variant on this standard core. For example, Thundurus-Incarnate was a popular sixth option resulting in the term CHALK-T.
      </p>

  <!-- Acronym-->
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p style="font-size: 20px">
            <b>
              Japan Sand - - - 
            </b>
          </p>
        </td>

  <!--Arconym Pokemon-->
        <td>
          <img src="https://www.serebii.net/art/th/373-m.png">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="https://www.serebii.net/art/th/248.png">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="https://www.serebii.net/art/th/530.png">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="https://www.serebii.net/art/th/591.png">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!--Arconym descption-->
      <p>
        Japan Sand was a team popularized in Japan - hence the name - and almost always featured the four Pokemon core of Mega Salamence, Tyranitar, Excadrill and Amoonguss. A common fifth Pokemon added to the team was Belly Drum Huge Power Azumarill to pair with Amoonguss.
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have multiple head and html tags and no body / things outside your html tag. Is that a copy paste error or does your code actually look this way? If it actually looks like this, you Should look up how to format an html doc.

Comment: This isn't a copy paste error, but the coding works and produces the information I want present on my site. The only issue I'm coming across is the fact that the resizing coding doesn't directly affect the images I've coded. There's a possibility that <body> is not needed considering that I'm working out of Squarespace.

Comment: You need a body and exactly 1 html tag with everything inside of it and Exactly 1 head tag. No other error can be corrected until you correct that. Look up how to format an html doc properly.

Comment: Is the updated coding formatted correctly now?

Comment: Do you use table for layout?

Comment: So, the text that I have going before the images ("CHALK - - -" for example) without being in the table coding would align itself with the bottom of the images, but I want it to align with the center of the images.